# How to personalize the display of a ActiveRecord object in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an object that when printed on the rails console looks like:

```
> Model.first
MyModel{
    id: 1
  role: 2
status: 5
}
```

What options do I have in order to change the `role` and `status` to a more descriptive value? Let's say I have a hash on `MyModel` to specify what each thing is

```
 class MyModel < AR
    STATUSES = {0: active, 1: inactive, etc...}
```

How I can customize the output to use those values for printing using only the  rails console? I've tried with inspect without success.

PD. I'm aware that `enum` is an option, but for other reasons I would really like to customize the output of printing this object in console. I'm prety sure it's possible as AwesomePrint does it. For example, I also would like to hide some fields.

Comment: yup I'm aware enum is an alternative, but for other reasons i would like to really personalize the ouput of an AR object in console.

Answer (score 0):

As [stated in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44916764/how-to-personalize-the-display-of-a-activerecord-object-in-console#comment76810703_44916764), you could use `enum` to get the result you are looking for. I think that is the best option you've got.

To use an `enum` just add it your model, for example:

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  enum status: { active: 0, inactive: 1, other: 5 }
  enum role: { admin: 0, user: 1, superuser: 2 }
end
```

Notice that the *key* in the hash is a symbol with the description you want and the *value* is the data stored in the db.

Example:

```
pp MyModel.first
#<MyModel:0x007f89e736a600
 id: 4,
 role: "superuser",
 status: "other">
```

Additionally, with enums in place, you have a lot of methods created for you, so you don't need to use the db values again. Check [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) for more info.